# Polymer Element Project with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I'm trying out Polymer 3.0 for the first time, and I want to build an Element library that is expected to have about 20 components. I followed the guide for creating an Element project from [the documentation](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/create-element-polymer-cli) and selecting `polymer-3-element` from the `polymer init` menu. However, the set up that the tool generates seems to be designed only for a single component. How can I extend this setup so that I can bundle and test multiple components?

Comment: and you can't just create another file in your project and import it in your main one?